# godaddy webhosting root directory

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, cloud, web-hosting

im using go-daddy to learn web hosting ...

[image: /usr/local/apache]

so i had problem and i reset my account because i thought something change some settings in the server..

[image: cpanel interface web root dir]
[image: default root DIR]

after i reset the account i still have the same problem that my web root DIR is in (ht-docs owned by root) which i cant edit ...

[image: documentroot apache config]

this is the effective root directory .. i dont know why its not (public_html)

i ve allready asked in godaddy before about this and figured out my self the root directory by searching html code in all files in my server
 (`grep -isr "html code" /*`)

https://uk.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Web-Hosting/public-html/td-p/51705

note: im newbie in linux .. i've just purchased godaddy account to learn web hosting ..

Comment: this is totally not professional server neither infrastructure adminstration its just apache and basic linux hosting question ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to edit stuf in the default `htdocs` dir while the document root is set to `/public_html/www` in your user dir, according to the control panel screenshot you provided?

Look for `public_html/www` in your user dir, it should be `~/public_html/www`, which is a shortcut to `/home/YOUR_USER/public_html/www`

PS: be careful asyour last screenshot shows `/home/YOUR_USER/public_html` as the document root, while the control panel one as `www` on top of it (but it might just be to handle subdomains)

Comment: Hello, thanks ... this is the problem .. that i EDIT my files in (~/public_html) but it doesnt get updated so i ve (grep all files with the html code of the website) and found that apache is using (/usr/local/apache/htdocs) ..

Comment: It will by default, but it doesn't mean the virtual host used for you domain doesn't. Also, like I said, the 'www' folder probably maps to the www host. So check if you access your domain with our without. Otherwise, contact Go Daddy.